# Convert JSON to grails object

Tags: json, grails

I have a JSON object in my view page, I pass it via params, lets say 'params.userInfo' and in the controller, I want it to parse to an object 'User' which I have created. How do I do it ?
The user object may be such

```
class User{
  string name
  string age
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
def user = new User(params.userInfo)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the information from Grails documentation here: http://grails.org/Converters+Reference